# delete method shopping cart angular error

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, api

I would simply like to delete an item on click, I made a code but I have error, I've been stuck on it for 2 days.

ERROR TypeError: this.addedBook.indexOf is not a function

Thank you for your help

**ts.file**

```
export class PaymentComponent implements OnInit {

  addedBook: any = [];
  product:any;

  constructor(private bookService: BookService) { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.addedBook = this.bookService.getBookList();
  }

  delete() {
    this.addedBook.splice(this.addedBook.indexOf(this.product), 1);
  }

}
```

**html**

```
 <div class="product" *ngFor="let book of addedBook | async">
        <div class="product-image">
            <img [src]="book.cover" alt="book">
        </div>
        <div class="product-details">
            <div class="product-title">{{book.title}}</div>
        </div>
        <div class="product-price">{{book.price | currency: 'EUR'}}</div>
        <div class="product-quantity">
            <input type="number" value="1" min="1">
        </div>
        <div class="product-removal">
            <button class="remove-product" (click)="delete()">
                Supprimé
            </button>
        </div>
```

I have an interface like this

**interface**

```
export interface BookType {
    title: string;
    price: number;
    cover: string;
    synopsis: string;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you switched `addedBook` and `product` in your `delete` method and with some more typings instead of the any's that would be much clearer. Also the `1` is likely supposed to belong to `splice`. Your code, however, provides the `1` to `indexOf`. Try

```
delete() {
    this.addedBook.splice(this.addedBook.indexOf(this.product), 1);
  }
```

Comment: thank you for yor help, i have this error : TypeError: this.addedBook.indexOf is not a function